# The html is not shown based on locally saved variables

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, local-storage, lifecycle

I have a component that needs to display html based on a boolean variable. I make this variable the same as the one I set in the localStorage.
So if I click on foo, I set it to false both as a variable and in the localStorage. If I click on the bar I set it to true.
Now, before loading the component I'm going to get this variable, and I make it the same as the one I have locally, so if I clicked on foo, when I reload the component, the variable is false, and therefore the html should show me foo. but I don't understand why he shows me bars!!!
It's a bit complicated to explain I hope you understand from the code:

```
 <template>
   <div id="app">
     <h2 v-if="!isTrue">FOO</h2>
     <h2 v-else>BAR</h2>

    <button @click="foo()">FOO</button>
    <button @click="bar()">BAR</button>
   </div>
 </template>

 <script>
 export default {
   name: 'App',
   data: function () {
     return {
       isTrue: null,
     };
   },
   created() {
     const boh = localStorage.getItem('boh');
     this.isTrue = boh;
     console.log('boh', boh);
     console.log('isTrue', this.isTrue);
   },
   methods: {
     foo() {
       this.isTrue = false;
       localStorage.setItem('boh', false);
     },
     bar() {
       this.isTrue = true;
       localStorage.setItem('boh', true);
     },
   },
 };
 </script>
```

I am attaching an example on stackblitz so maybe you can do tests:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-b3ieft?file=src%2FApp.vue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because a variable you saved in the localStorage is a string. When you do:

```
const boh = localStorage.getItem('boh');
this.isTrue = boh;
```

Actually you get:

```
this.isTrue = 'true';
```

And this string is always `true`.

To avoid this you could check if it is `true` string:

```
const boh = localStorage.getItem('boh');
this.isTrue = boh === 'true';
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-mnuhbr?file=src%2FApp.vue

Answer (score 1):

Adding on to @Georgy's answer. To escape an unnecessary check, it is a good practice for booleans to be **stringified** while setting the localstorage, and **parsed** when getting the item.

***Setting***

```
localStorage.setItem("boh", JSON.stringify(false));
```

***Getting***

```
const boh = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('boh'))
```